# how to give default alert function behaviour to qtip 2 alert

Tags: javascript, qtip, qtip2

I am using qtip2 for displaying the alert messages for my web application ( as shown at http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#dialogues )

my code is

1) for dialogue

```
function dialogue(content, title) {
    /* 
    * Since the dialogue isn't really a tooltip as such, we'll use a dummy
    * out-of-DOM element as our target instead of an actual element like document.body
    */
    $('<div />').qtip(
                {
                    content: {
                        text: content
                       , title: {
                           text: 'PMGSY ',
                           button: 'Close'
                       }
                    },
                    position: {
                        my: 'center', at: 'center', // Center it...
                        target: $(window) // ... in the window
                    },
                    show: {
                        ready: true, // Show it straight away
                        modal: {
                            on: true, // Make it modal (darken the rest of the page)...
                            blur: false, // ... but don't close the tooltip when clicked
                            escape: false
                        }
                    },
                    hide: false, // We'll hide it maunally so disable hide events

                    style: {
                        classes: 'qtip-shadow qtip-rounded qtip-dialogue', // Optional shadow...
                        widget: true //themeroller
                    },

                    events: {
                        // Hide the tooltip when any buttons in the dialogue are clicked
                        render: function (event, api) {
                            $('button', api.elements.content).click(api.hide);
                        },
                        // Destroy the tooltip once it's hidden as we no longer need it!
                        hide: function (event, api) { api.destroy(); }
                    }
                });
}
```

2) to call it as alert

```
function Alert(message) {
    // Content will consist of the message and an ok button
    var message = $('<p />', { text: message }),
    ok = $('<button />', { text: 'Ok', 'class': 'full' });
    dialogue(message.add(ok), 'Alert!');
}
```

the problem is when i use it ,its does not block the further processing until user click on ok button (like default alert function).

e.g this alert does not even show up.

```
Alert("Customised alerts"); //this doesent show      
window.location.replace("/Home/startPage");
```

how to make my custom alert mimic the default alert function ?
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
ok = $('<button />', { text: 'Ok', 'class': 'full' });
```

with

```
ok = $('<button />', { text: 'Ok', 'class': 'full' }).click(function(){
    window.location.replace("/Home/startPage");
});
```